# Standalone .jar runs great, but when embedded in HTML, framerate drops to 1 fps

Tags: java, html, google-chrome, applet, embed

I have a single .jar file that I create by using the runnable .jar file export function in Eclipse. This file runs flawlessly when you just download it and run it. Now I'm trying to embed it in an HTML file, but having trouble.

[Here is the standalone jar](http://uncc.ath.cx/applets/Voronoi_Standalone/Voronoi_Standalone_Local.jar)

Here is the page where I attempt to embed the .jar file. I could not make it run on it's own, but If I took the Main.class file from the bin/ directory of my Project and included that too, it almost works.

```
<html>
<head><title>Voronoi Cells</title></head>
<body>
<applet code="Main.class" archive="Voronoi_Standalone_Local.jar" width="600" Height="500">
</applet>
</body>
</html>
```

[Here is that page online](http://uncc.ath.cx/applets/Voronoi_Standalone/)

With this arrangement, in Chrome, the applet shows, but the framerate is only around 1 fps.

It crashes Firefox.

It works fine it Safari!

Who cares what it does in IE.

What is the correct applet tag I should use? I would prefer to reference only the single standalone .jar file if possible. Why is the framerate so bad in Chrome?

Comment: I just want to say that this is pretty cool.

Comment: And that it runs fine on Firefox 3.6.3 under OS X.

Comment: Runs at the same speed in IE8 / FF 3.6.6  / Chrome 6.0.477 / Opera 10.60 under windows xp

Comment: also runs fine on chromium daily builds on 64bit linux

Comment: Fails horribly under Chrome 5 & Mac OS. What's your OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice one there.

I would suggest adding a frame number counter and displaying it overlaid on the frame.

My guess is that you will find that the update frequency putting the Java frame data inside the page is too low, so you have plenty of updates, but they don't make it to the page.

I would suggest opening a new JFrame and display in that to see if that helps.  If yes, then this is a plugin issue to the "hole" in the browser page.